# Error fetching job: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 7419

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.7

Using Ruby -v 2.7.5 and Rails -v 6.1.7.6
I am using [gem 'faktory_worker_ruby', '~> 1.0'](https://github.com/contribsys/faktory_worker_ruby), for the background jobs.

while starting the [faktory](https://github.com/contribsys/faktory/blob/main/Changes.md#170) demon getting the following error:

```
 Error fetching job: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 7419
```

Please guide the way around to get it working fine.

Answer (score 0):

we can use docker to do it:
install docker faktory the run it on the ports:

```
docker pull contribsys/faktory

 docker run --rm -it -p 127.0.0.1:7419:7419 -p 127.0.0.1:7420:7420 contribsys/faktory:latest
```

Now inside the rails application run it will work fine:

```
bundle exec faktory-worker
```

related blog: [https://medium.com/shogun-team/faktory-tutorial-with-workers-in-go-24dd2aa69f3a#:~:text=Installing%20Faktory,to%20use%20the%20docker%20image](https://medium.com/shogun-team/faktory-tutorial-with-workers-in-go-24dd2aa69f3a#:%7E:text=Installing%20Faktory,to%20use%20the%20docker%20image).